# JavaFX thread always runnable

Tags: java, swing, javafx, profiling

Why does JavaFX Application thread always RUNNABLE?

The following screen from YourKit profiler (VisualVM shows similar picture though):

[image]

Yellow parts mean **waiting** state, light green - **runnable** and dark green when thread actually does work (visible in stacktrace)

Swing's EDT waits for events and waiting otherwise, but what actually does JavaFX thread under the hood? Whether its 100% runnable state may cause performance leaks?

Answer (score 3):

*Background on thread states*

According to the [Thread.State.RUNNABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE) documentation:

> Thread state for a runnable thread. A thread in the runnable state is executing in the Java virtual machine but it may be waiting for other resources from the operating system such as processor.

Most of the time, the JavaFX application thread is waiting on operating system level callbacks, so it shows up as RUNNABLE in a profiler even though it is usually waiting.  It is because the wait is occurring in native code rather than a sleep style call in the JVM.

You can see from this [Java thread state UML diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/java-6-thread-state-machine-diagram-example.html) that there are different methods required for Java threads to enter different states.  In Swing, one of these methods is used to get the EDT into a waiting state, but similar methods are not used in JavaFX.

*How JavaFX works*

The [architecture of the JavaFX system](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438) is based upon a timed pulse, which by default will fire 60 times a second.  To get a smooth animated display without image tearing, (I think) the system can enable a vsync timer so that the pulses are synchronized with the display.  A standard JVM does not know about an OS specific vsync timer, so the JavaFX system uses native code to cause the JavaFX application thread to wait on the OS supplied vsync timer.

*It's not an issue*

> Whether its 100% runnable state may cause performance leaks?

No, I do not think the state will cause performance leaks.

One thing to be aware of is that the JavaFX application thread is geared for UI updates, so things that run on it will only run at most 60 times per second by default.  So if you use something like a PauseTransition and set the duration of the pause to Duration.millis(10), the pause won't actually be 10 milliseconds, but a 60th of second (approx 16 milliseconds).

If you have things which are extremely fine grained time sensitive you are probably better to use something like a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) or some high resolution OS native timer, but for most people this is not a real consideration that they need to worry about as they won't be dealing with such high resolution timing.

The main performance consideration when using the JavaFX application thread is just to make sure that you get all your work done and release the thread (preferably in under a sixtieth of a second), so that the UI and event processing is not held up by your application, but that consideration is the same as for Swing, so nothing new there.

*Pulse Definition*

From the JavaFX architecture overview (to help understand how pulses relate to event processing):

> When a pulse is fired, the state of the elements on the scene graph is synchronized down to the rendering layer. A pulse enables application developers a way to handle events asynchronously. This important feature allows the system to batch and execute events on the pulse.
>   . . .
>   The Glass Windowing Toolkit is responsible for executing the pulse events. It uses the high-resolution native timers to make the execution.

*Disclaimer*

A disclaimer on this answer is that some of it is speculation on my part, so it may be slightly incorrect, but I think it is probably a reasonable approximation of the truth.

*Further info*

If you are interesting in investigating more, you can review the [Timer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/2ad159b40c2c/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/glass/ui/Timer.java) and [WinTimer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/tip/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/glass/ui/win/WinTimer.java) code or other code in the open-jfx code base or ask further JavaFX architecture questions on the [openjfx-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) JavaFX developer mailing list.  The developers there are more knowledgeable about such things than me and will be able to do things like validate my speculation on such as whether the pulses are vsynced.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed response!